# How to send image and data as two different parameters through ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, parameters, image-uploading

```
var data = new FormData()
jQuery.each(jQuery('#file')[0].files, function(i, file){
   data.append('file-'+i, file)
})    
$.ajax({
  method : 'post',
  url : SERVER,
  processData : false,
  contentType : false,
  //async : false,
  data : { id: "2458" , file : data },
  success : function(response){
     if(response.success==1){
        //do something
     }
  }
});
```

I need to upload an image to a third party api which accepts image file and id as parameter. However, whenever I am trying to use the above code, only image object is being sent. I need the id also to be sent. [screenshot shows only image object being sent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QLgi.png)

Quick help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submitting multi part form for file upload

```
<form id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="firstFile" id="file_1" data-filename="image.jpg">
    <input type="file" name="SecondFile" id="file_2" data-filename="image2.jpg">
    <button id="myFormButton">click</button>
</form>
var formData = new FormData();

$("#myFormButton").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var inputs = $("#myForm input");
    $.each(inputs, function (obj, v) {
        var file = v.files[0];
        var filename = $(v).attr("data-filename");
        var name = $(v).attr("id");
        formData.append(name, file, filename);
    });
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open('POST', 'your server URL', true);
    xhr.send(formData);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should send only the `FormData` object in the request. To add the `id` parameter, `append()` it to the `FormData` exactly as you did with the files:

```
var data = new FormData()
$.each(jQuery('#file')[0].files, function(i, file){
   data.append('file-' + i, file)
})    
data.append('id', '2458');

$.ajax({
  method: 'post',
  url: SERVER,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  data: data,
  success: function(response) {
     if (response.success == 1) { // you should change the success flag to a boolean
        //do something
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried this way, but the API is not accepting through this format. They require both to be sent as two different parameters.

Comment: They are still sent as two different parameters, they are now just both encoded the same way (as multipart). What is the error you get?

Comment: I am getting as 'id not sent'

Answer (score 1):

```
var imageDetails = {};

FR.onload = function(e) {
    $('#img'+imageIndex).attr( "src",  e.target.result );
    $('#imageHolder'+imageIndex).attr('value', e.target.result );
    imageDetails.images[expectedFile.replace(/\.  [^/.]+$/, "")]=(e.target.result); 
}            

FR.readAsDataURL( target.files[0] );

jqxhr = $.ajax( {
    'url':"https://url",
    'data': JSON.stringify(imageDetails),
    'type':'post',
    'contentType': "application/json"
})
```

Comment: This one is not helping out